# Check if file path is block device in Python

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

I have some file path in Python under Linux and I need to figure out if it's a block device - representation of disk or partition. This information is visible when typing ls -l, e.g.

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 09-12 18:01 /dev/sda1
```

I mean letter **b** on start of this output. Is this possible to get something like this in Python using built in libraries? Eventually I can use subprocess to fetch "ls -l" result and check if first character is correct, but i feel that there could be nicer solution for this. Unfortunately I can't find this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `stat` lib using [stat.S_ISBLK](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISBLK) with [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: import stat

In [3]: mode = os.stat("/dev/sda2").st_mode

In [4]: stat.S_ISBLK(mode)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: mode = os.stat("/dev/sr0").st_mode

In [6]: stat.S_ISBLK(mode)
Out[6]: True
```

Answer (score 9):

Since 3.4 `pathlib` offers convenience function [Path.is_block_device()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_block_device)

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path('/dev/vda')
>>> p.is_block_device()
True
```